# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null

Tags: android, google-maps, inputstream, mapactivity

When i use this code to find the distance between two geo points and draw path between them, i get this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null

public class MapRouteActivity extends MapActivity {
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    MapView mapView;
    private Road mRoad;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                double fromLat = 49.85, fromLon = 24.016667;
                double toLat = 50.45, toLon = 30.523333;
                String url = RoadProvider
                        .getUrl(fromLat, fromLon, toLat, toLon);
                InputStream is = getConnection(url);
                mRoad = RoadProvider.getRoute(is);
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
            textView.setText(mRoad.mName + " " + mRoad.mDescription);
            MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(mRoad, mapView);
            List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            listOfOverlays.clear();
            listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
            mapView.invalidate();
        };
    };

    private InputStream getConnection(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
            is = conn.getInputStream();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return is;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have the internet permission?

Comment: Does this code get caught? URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection(); is = conn.getInputStream(); Because that means your is variable is still null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `InputStream` is null you need to fix it:

```
InputStream is = getConnection(url);
if (is != null) {
   // do your work
}
else {
  // logging error
}
```

In your case your method `getConnection(url)` returns `null` so first check if you have permission for Internet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```